# Background image (for TextView) as big as the TextView content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I set a background image to a `TextView`:

```
<TextView
   ...
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/fumetto"
   ...
/>
```

The problem is that now the `TextView` size is not as big as its content, but it's as big as the background image.

Is there a way to make the background image adapt to the TextView size and not to make the TextView adapt to the size of its background image?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should works fine.. please check your parent layout or post some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `9 Patch` Drawable.
Here is the [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made a 9 patch image, but now android studio tells me that there is a "duplicate" resorces error, since now I have fumetto.png and fumetto.9.png.
If deleted fumetto.png  (after even cleaning and rebulding the project) I get another error.
Do you know how to solve this problem on android studio?

Comment: what is the error you get after deleting the drawable? @MDP

Answer (score 0):

Use a shape drawable from resource

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
     android:text="adswss" />
```

button_border

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="15dp"></corners>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/color_bg" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>'
```